# Create bootable Mojave USB from Mojave OS

Tags: macos-mojave

My Mac already have Mojave OS installed and I am trying to find a way to create a bootable USB so that I can install a fresh copy of the OS when on a new disk.

I've found Mojave OS in appstore as I alread have the os installed and have an updated to the latest version I don't see anything that downloads.

So I don't see any installer in the Applications too.

My Question:: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250139745

Comment: you need to re-fetch the full installer from the app store, as it is deleted on successful update, then use `createinstallmedia ` ... or just use Internet Recovery on the new drive/machine.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Please note you need a USB drive with atleat 8GB, all of the contents in the drive will be erased with this installation.

I've solve the issue by:
1. I've update the os.
2. Browsed the appstore for macOS Mojave
3. Get to download, and it takes around 15-20 mins depends on your computer speed.
4. Open once the download is complete installer will open
5. Close the installer (User Command+Q)
6. Open Terminal from Applications>Utilities>Terminal
7. Type the below command sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/[your usb dirve name] 
8. Press enter and when prompted click enter your passowrd.
9.If you wish to continue type (Y) then press return: key in Y and press enter

There you go, your installation media wil be ready when Copying to disk shows 100%.

Comment: You can attach screenshots to enrich your answer. No need to reply this comment.